Where to ask questions about formal languages and parsing?
I want ask about parsing, LL table creation, FIRST, FOLLOW sets. I want ask about detecting grammar ambiguity.

What a question is "about" isn't just a matter of the topics or tags; it depends on what kind of information you're trying to obtain about those topics.
Stack Overflow is appropriate if you have a concrete programming problem that relates to the task of parsing a formal language, building an LL table, etc.
Software Engineering may be more appropriate if you're asking more abstractly about the algorithm needed to compute a FIRST or FOLLOW set, or e.g. trying to determine whether a given parsing technique is suitable for a specific input language.
Programming Language Design and Implementation may be more appropriate if you're trying to design a parser for a specific language and determine what it should do in various circumstances. "Detecting grammar ambiguity" is vague, but I think your question will most likely fit in this category.
Keep in mind that many questions are suitable (or can be re-framed to be suitable) on more than one Stack Exchange site.

Some aspects seem on-topic at Computer Science.

I would suggest asking on Stack Overflow. I see a bunch of questions on those topics there.
